# GOPATH not set in VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Golang newb here.

[image]

Why is VSCode telling me that GOPATH is not set? I restarted VSCode a few times. The env variable is set as you can see from the terminal, and it's set to `$HOME/go`.

```
export GOROOT=$HOME/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$HOME/go/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

I am using the golang plugin from lukehoban:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go

And I have this in workspace settings:

```
{
    "go.gopath": "/Users/alexamil/go"
}
```

anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with VSCode, but in general GOPATH is optional (the default is `$HOME/go`), but `GOROOT=$HOME/go` is incorrect. You should almost never set GOROOT, and it should never be the same as GOPATH.

Comment: thanks..tbh guys I have never read so much conflicting info about env variables for any language, and that's not your fault.